# PHP freezes when using for loop for big array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, freeze

I have some troubles when trying to run this script:

```
<?php

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","mysqlpassword","MarcTextOldBib");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
$db_abfrage = "SELECT `cid` , `field_data` FROM T1xx" ;
$j=0;
$db_ausgabe = $mysqli->query($db_abfrage);
while($row = $db_ausgabe->fetch_object()){
    $names[$j] = array( "cid"           => $row->cid,
                        "field_data"    => $row->field_data,
                     );
    $j++;
}


$mysqli->close();

echo"
<table border='1'>
<thead><tr>
<th>ID</th> <th>Name</th>
</tr></thead>";

$ID=1;
$size = count($names);

for ( $i = 0; $i <= $size; $i++ ){
    $cid = $names[$i][cid];
    echo "<tr>";

    while( $ID != $names[$i][cid] ) {
        echo "<td>".($ID)."</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $ID++;
    }

    if( ($ID) == $names[$i][cid] ) {
        echo "<td>" . ($ID) . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $names[$i][field_data] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $ID++;
    }

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

When I set the for-loop to only "50" instead of count($names), it works like charm. But when using count($names) my computer freezes completly. count($names) is 2788.

Comment: Returning that many rows in a web application is inefficient, obviously

Comment: How much data are you returning? What type of data does `field_data` contain? For example, if it's something like a column containing tinyints, something else is probably wrong. If it's a text field with each row containing 2mb, are you surprised?

Comment: Is while( $ID != $names[$i][cid] ) { meant to be while( $ID != $names[$i]['cid'] ) { ? Also this while loop is open to being potentially infinite, hence the freeze, maybe there are instances of this happening with a $row after 50?

Comment: first off all you have infinite loop in your code, so check my answer and let fix all together :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have very weird code, I've simplified as much as I get the idea,
but what did you try to get with `$ID++` still out of my understanding.

If oyu explain I will fix the rest for you:

```
<?php

$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","mysqlpassword","MarcTextOldBib");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
$db_abfrage = "SELECT `cid` , `field_data` FROM T1xx" ;
$db_ausgabe = $mysqli->query($db_abfrage);
$names= array()
while($row = $db_ausgabe->fetch_assoc()){
    $names[] = $row
}


$mysqli->close();

echo"
<table border='1'>
<thead><tr>
<th>ID</th> <th>Name</th>
</tr></thead>";

$ID=1;

foreach ($names as $row ){
    $cid = $row['cid'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . ($ID) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . ($ID != $row['cid'])?'':$row['field_data'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $ID++;


}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

put "cid" in quotes.

Change:

```
$names[$i][cid]
```

To:

```
$names[$i]['cid']
```

And same goes for

```
$names[$i]['fieldData']
```

Comment: Wow that worked! Why is it, that it still works without quotes, but not quite that fast?

Comment: just using "cid" without quotes, PHP would try to find if there's a constant named "cid". If not, it would return a null. An in your case, this was causing your while loop to go forever - hence the freeze.